# How to map RestTemplate with multiple response content?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I must consume a REST API with `RestTemplate` which doesn't follows good patterns, like using HTTP status codes, for example.

I have both below response contents.

### Success response:

```
{
    "435": {
        "Codigo": "435",
        "Tipo": "",
        "Corretor": "62",
        "Cliente": "48304",
        "DataHora": "2016-04-27 14:18:24",
        "DataHoraAtualizacao": "",
        "Assunto": "Visita - Imóvel 2",
        "Local": "",
        "Texto": "",
        "DataHoraInicio": "2016-04-28 12:00:00",
        "DataHoraFinal": "2016-04-28 12:20:00"
    },
    "687": {
        "Codigo": "687",
        "Tipo": "",
        "Corretor": "20",
        "Cliente": "33040",
        "DataHora": "2016-07-18 17:09:28",
        "DataHoraAtualizacao": "",
        "Assunto": "Visita - Imóvel 2",
        "Local": "",
        "Texto": "teste",
        "DataHoraInicio": "2016-07-28 08:00:00",
        "DataHoraFinal": "2016-07-28 09:00:00"
    }}
```

We can note a map structure, as follows::

```
Map<String, MyObject> myObjects;
```

#### MyObject Class

```
public class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("Codigo")
    private String codigo;

    @JsonProperty("Tipo")
    private String tipo;

    @JsonProperty("Corretor")
    private String corretor;

    @JsonProperty("Cliente")
    private String cliente;

    @JsonProperty("DataHora")
    private String dataHora;

    @JsonProperty("DataHoraAtualizacao")
    private String dataHoraAtualizacao;

    @JsonProperty("Assunto")
    private String assunto;

    @JsonProperty("Local")
    private String local;

    @JsonProperty("Texto")
    private String texto;

    @JsonProperty("DataHoraInicio")
    private String dataHoraInicio;

    @JsonProperty("DataHoraFinal")
    private String dataHoraFinal;

}
```

### Error response (with no objects to return):

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "message": "A pesquisa não retornou resultados."
}
```

**How I should map a Java class in order to solve both cases?**

Answer (score 1):

um... that API is awful, can you ask them to change it? at least to use proper HTTP codes?

If not, you could deserialize first into a `Map<String, JsonNode>` and then depending on the presence of the `status` field, deserialize into the appropriate type:

```
String json = ...
Map<String, JsonNode> response = mapper.readValue(json, ...);

if (response.get("status") != null) {
    // its an error, deserialize into Error type
    Error error = mapper.readValue(json, Error.class);
else {
    // not an error, deserialize into MyObject
    MyObject obj = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Response class with a property `Map<String, MyObject> myObjects` and add `status` and `message` to the Response class, don't forget to annotate with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.
However the json you get back from RestTemplate "might"not automatically serialize to `myObjects`, you might need to do a little formatting with the response to fit your Response Class below.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
    ignoreUnknown = true
)
public class Response{
  Map<String, MyObject> myObjects;
  String status;
  String message;
}
```

Comment: Error response is ok, but success response didn't work. It's assigning always NULL.