# Consume REST API returns different xml response + Java

Tags: java, xml, rest, resttemplate, xml-deserialization

We are trying to consume third party REST API which returns a different response for success and error scenario. Below the xml response for both success & error.

**Success**

```xml
<Customer>
    <Account>
        ...
    </Account>
</Customer>
```

**Error**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Errors>
    <ErrorDetail>
        ...
    </ErrorDetail>
</Errors>
```

We are using RestTemplate to consume this API. 
We need a suggestion to consume this API and deserialize the response XML to corresponding POJO objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do both success and error responses have the same HTTP status code?

Comment: Yes @Phil, the REST API always returns 200 status code for both success & error.

Comment: Wow, that's a bad API so I definitely understand your pain on this one. Check out this post ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294619/how-to-map-resttemplate-with-multiple-response-content. There's a few more that turn up if you search Google for _"spring resttemplate response success error same status different content"_

Comment: That seems completely BAD API design, there must be some header level information which should tell about success vs failure, 
else you will have to scan the response message pick the Root element snd then create pojo class.

Comment: Get response as string from resttemplate then manually convert it error POJO, if that fails then convert to your actual POJO. it has some overhead.